# blank video with external picture and fade in effect

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to create a 5 seconds video with a picture in the middle that appears with a fade-in effect.

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=640x360:d=5 -i logo.png -filter_complex "[1:v]fade=in:0:30[a];[a][0:v]scale2ref=oh*mdar:ih/2[2nd][ref];[ref][2nd]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2"  output5.mp4
```

But the picture never appears, instead if I remove the fadIn property the picture appears but without the effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single image is treated as a video of 1 frame. You have to enable loop and optionally specify a duration, else fade filter has no frames to work with. Since your fade duration is 30 frames and default assigned framerate for images is 25 fps, I've set a duration of 1.25 s == 32 frames.

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=640x360:d=5 -loop 1 -t 1.25 -i logo.png -filter_complex "[1:v]fade=in:0:30[a];[a][0:v]scale2ref=oh*mdar:ih/2[2nd][ref];[ref][2nd]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2"  output5.mp4
```