# Overlay with fade in-out not showing

Tags: ffmpeg, overlay, fade

I can actually add an overlay image in the center of a video from a start time A to an end time B.

Reading here and there I tried to add a `fade-in/fade-out` effect to my overlayed image but the result is the image not showing at all in my final video.

This is my "experiment":

```
-i output.mp4 -i 1.png -filter_complex "[1:v]format=rgba,scale=300:300,fade=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,fade=out:st=5:d=1[im];[0][im]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h - overlay_h) / 2:enable='between(t,0,5)'" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy output_0.mp4
```

If in understood:

```
fade=in:st=0:d=1
```

Means that the image should appear at 0'' with a fade-in effect of 1'' duration

```
fade=out:st=5:d=1
```

Means that the image should disappear at 5'' with a fade-out effect of 1'' duration

Isn't it?

Second part would be to add a zoom effect of the image when it is fading in, can I combine the fade-in and the zoom effect toghether?

I think that something like this should zoom for a duration of 3 seconds my image overlay, can I add it with another "," separating the filter to the overlayed image?

```
zoompan=z='if(lte(zoom,1.0),1.5,max(1.001,zoom-0.0015))':d=3
```

Thanks

### edit:

The video is 10 sec long. I want an image to be shown with fade in-out and zoom in from 0 to 5 and another from 5 to 10 with the same effect

**Step 1: adding fade in-out**

```
-i 0_vid.mp4 -loop 1 -t 1 -i 1.png -filter_complex "[1:v]format=rgba,fade=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,fade=out:st=4:d=1:alpha=1[im];[0][im]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h - overlay_h)/2:shortest=1" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy output_0.mp4
```

With this solution the fade in works, but the fade out is not even taken in consideration.

If I add the zoom:

```
-i 0_vid.mp4 -loop 1 -t 1 -i 1.png -filter_complex "[1:v]format=rgba,zoompan=z='if(lte(zoom,1.0),1.5,max(1.3875,zoom-0.0015))':d=625,fade=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,fade=out:st=4:d=1:alpha=1[im];[0][im]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h - overlay_h)/2:shortest=1" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy output_0.mp4
```

This way the image is stretched full screen width and the height is cut. But during the 5 sec animation the image is not resized as normal.

What I'm aiming for is the image to be zoomed in the video but not to be cut/stretched. I would like to have the image to look smaller at the start and bigger at the end. Is it possible?

And also, what am I doing wrong with fade out animation

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/48077012/5726027 for why the fade isn't working. I'm using zoompan instead of loop to generate frames.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i output.mp4 -i 1.png -filter_complex "[1:v]format=rgba,scale=300:300,zoompan=z='if(lte(zoom,1.0),1.5,max(1.3875,zoom-0.0015))':d=125:s=300x300,fade=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,fade=out:st=4:d=1:alpha=1[im];[0][im]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h - overlay_h) / 2:enable='between(t,0,5)'" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy output_0.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I write here both for comment and answer. With the comment I can now see the fade-in animation, but I can't see neither the fade-out and the zoom. Probably there might be an error with the loop statement, might be? I don't see also the fade-out animation, only the fade-in worked I added `-loop 1 -t 1` (I added new code in question)

Comment: I can't still solve te problem, try if possible to have a look at my edited question, I explained it better. Thanks for your help